# No REPLIT_DB_URL environment variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, fetch, replit-database

When I try using the Replit database, I get told "Only absolute URLs are supported". Then I tried finding the REPLIT_DB_URL with 'printenv' in the shell. There was no variable with that name. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `echo $REPLIT_DB_URL` into the shell.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll delete my answer. I don't know why that would be different from what OP already tried.